# Any way to use ":" to access a row for a 1D NumPy array

Tags: numpy, matlab

```
Import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,3])
```

Is there any way to achive A[1,:], in MATLAB it is fine

Comment: A[1,:] would work in python for two dimensional array, [1,2,3] has only one dimension. Either A[:] could work in Python, though. If you want to treat your array as 2 dimensional in numpy, you have to tell it explicitly.

Comment: Maybe you mean A[:] ?

Comment: see my answer by adding a "virtual" additional dimension to mimic what MatLab does.

Comment: Everything is 2d in MATLAB.  `A(1,:)` is still 2d.  For a 1d `numpy` array you can't use that 2d  indexing.  You can 'wrap' the array so it is 2d.  `np.matrix` subclass also aims to be matlab like.

Comment: Even if `A` is 2d, `A[0,:]` will not be.  You can't exactly replicate matlab.

Comment: @hpaulj everything is not 2D in MATLAB. In fact, either everything is 1D, or everything is ND. In MATLAB, `a=1` `a(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)` works. but ultimately, averything is a 1D array.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, when I started using MATLAB (v 3,5) everything was indeed 2d, only later was it extended to more trailing dimensions,  But there are still hints that the extension is a bit of a hack.  `numpy` tries to handle dimensions, from 0 up, seamlessly.   `numpy's` storage using a 1d data buffer, shape, and strides is well documented; I haven't seen anything comparable for MATLAB.   In any case, wayward MATLAB users often have difficulty with 0d and 1d arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat your numpy array as 2 dimensional array like in MatLab, you have to tell it explicitly, by creating a new array and using `np.newaxis` .

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([1,2,3])
print(A);

B = A[np.newaxis,:]
print(B)

# Here you go
print(B[0,:])
```

Test it on [Online Python](https://www.online-python.com/uwQI0nV23C)

*Side note:*
I wrote B[0,:], not B[1,:], because Python array indices are 0-based, not 1-based like MatLab.